# SimpleMDE: How to set Html preview to open anchor tag in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, simplemde

I am using [SimpleMDE](https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor) editor (version 1.10.1).

Is there a way to set Html preview to open anchor tag in a new tab with default `previewRender` which right now opens link in same tab. Reference image:

[image]

To my knowledge these are ways to achieve this -

1. I know we can set a custom `previewRender`, but making a custom parser function for all markdown syntax just to add `target="_blank"` for links will be a lot.
2. I can do this by simply changing function `togglePreview` in **`simplemde.js`** to replace anchor tag to have `target="_blank"` by this => `replace(/a href/g, 'a target="_blank" href')`, but that is not a permanent solution as this will be a hack which I will have to add on each update of SimpleMDE.

Apart from these 2 are there any other alternatives to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you [look at how simplemde renders html](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor/blob/master/src/js/simplemde.js#L1392), it simply uses [marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked). A quick search led me to find marked users having the [same issue we have](https://github.com/markedjs/marked/issues/655). In short you will have to set a custom `previewRender`, however it is not so terrible using the solution outlined from [csytan](https://github.com/csytan) on the marked issues page of github:

```
var marked = require('marked');

var customPreviewRender = function (text) {
    var renderer = new marked.Renderer();
    var linkRenderer = renderer.link;
    renderer.link = (href, title, text) => {
        var html = linkRenderer.call(renderer, href, title, text);
        return html.replace(/^<a /, '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" ');
    };
    return marked(text, { renderer: renderer });
}

var options = {
    previewRender: customPreviewRender 
};

var simpleMde = new SimpleMDE(options);
```